# How do I set a timestamp using Date() for a struct when it is initialized in Swift?

Tags: swift, foundation

**Imagine the following struct:**

```
struct DemoValue: Decodable { // i'm going to use this struct for storing JSON during a Combine pipeline decode
  let age = Date()
  // this property I'm hoping to be generated upon initialization

  // these properties match to keys on the incoming JSON payload
  let string: String
  let number: Double
  let isTrue: Bool
  // [...]
}
```

I'm trying to set the `.age` property when someDemoValue is initialized to the current time (which is what I thought is returned when you initialize a `Date()`

**I'm hoping to use it in the following way:**

```
let someDemoValue: DemoValue // this is initialized as part of decode during a Combine pipeline

func checkIfValueIsOld() {
  let fiveMinutesAgo = Date() - TimeInterval(300)
  if someDemoValue.age < fiveMinutesAgo {
    // execute some conditional...
  }
}
```

Is it possible to use it in the way that I am writing? When may I set the "Current Time" to this property, if not during initialization? During debug, the `.age` property is holding a reference to a `Date()` that is always January 1, 2001 - rather than any value close to the current date and time...even though the `fiveMinutesAgo` constant initializes properly to five minutes ago.

Comment: Subclass `NSObject` so that you can make an object with initial values?

Comment: I can't reproduce. Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: I think it would work, it's true that `age = Date()` will run upon initialization, just not sure how it works with JSONDecoder.

Answer (score 0):

There is some reason I realized I cannot just instantiate with `Date()`. In the effort of trying to create the minimal reproducible example, I happened across the solution. In order to get the above to work, I changed it to this:

```
struct DemoValue: Decodable { // i'm going to use this struct for storing JSON during a Combine pipeline decode
  let age: TimeInterval
  // this property I'm hoping to be generated upon initialization

  // these properties match to keys on the incoming JSON payload
  let string: String
  let number: Double
  let isTrue: Bool
  // [...]
}

var someDemoValue = DemoValue(age: Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate)

func checkIfValueIsOld() {
  let fiveMinutesAgo = Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate - TimeInterval(300)
  if someDemoValue.age < fiveMinutesAgo {
    // execute some conditional...
  }
}
```

Ironically this is not executable either - the important thing to take away is the use of a double to represent "Now", rather than an instantiation of Date().